# Filter SQL query result set based on arbitrary time

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am currently running the following SQL [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/de6bb/1)

and am trying to get the following to be true:

I only want the set of `cats` that have had  a `last_checked` value of some arbitrary time and are `sick`.  for the sake of discussion lets make it now minus 12 hours.  (`sysdate - Interval '12' hour`).  What I am getting back is the `cat` that was `last_checked` 11 hours ago, but that `cat` has a more recent status of now where he is no longer sick.  How can I construct a query in such a way that I ignore the old `sick` entry and only concern myself with the new `healthy` status?  By that I mean ignore this result because the cat is no longer sick.

**Question**

> So... do you want the most recent status regardless, the most recent
>   status of only those cats that have been sick in the given timeframe,
>   or only healthy cats?

I only want a status to be returned to me if it is the most recent (max) AND the status is also `sick`.  In the fiddle it will show an example what I don't want to happen, it will return the status of sick with the timestamp of `11 hours ago` but there is a more recent one.

**UPDATE**

The following function:

```
select cat_id, last_checked, sick
from
(
    select cat_id, last_checked, sick,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by cat_id order by last_checked desc) rn
    from cats
    where last_checked >= sysdate- INTERVAL '12' hour
) v
where rn = 1
and sick = 1;
```

provided by @podiluska  only retrieves the first result.  I need it to be on a `cat` by `cat` basis.

**Second Update**

The solution provided by Podiluska:

```
select cat_id, last_checked, sick
from
(
    select cat_id, last_checked, sick,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by cat_id order by last_checked desc) rn
    from cats
    where last_checked >= sysdate- INTERVAL '12' hour
) v
where rn = 1;
```

will work on small data sets.  The accepted answer (the one I used) will work most effectively on large data sets.

Comment: So... do you want the most recent status regardless, the most recent status of only those cats that have been sick in the given timeframe, or only healthy cats?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse responded to in the question body.

Comment: @Woot4Moo Answer is updated. Check that for a cat-by-cat basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so in case someone else runs into this same scenario that I did, you do not want to use an analytic function especially when your data is > 500 million records as mine is.  What you want to do is unwrap the analytic query into a sql statement that has the following form:

```
select colA,colB,...  
from  
(  
     select col1,col2,...
     from tables  
     where ...
)  results  
where ...
group by colA,colB
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Row_Number()` windowing function to get the most recent update...

```
select cat_id, last_checked, sick
from
(
    select cat_id, last_checked, sick,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by cat_id order by last_checked desc) rn
    from cats
    where last_checked >= sysdate- INTERVAL '12' hour
) v
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: Ok great, so this would work the same over a multi-table select as well I presume?

Comment: This is fairly close to what I need, however it only gets the first result in the set.  i need this function to be used per cat.  Any ideas on that?

Comment: @Woot4Moo Edited podiluska's answer. this should get you result on a cat by cat basis.